# Questions on universal reference and lvalue refs

Tags: c++

I have **three** questions in the code below, it would be nice if someone made three bullet points which addressed all of them:

```
template <typename T>
void fun(const T&& data) // 2) Isn't this a universal reference even with const?
{
}

template <typename T>
void fun2(const T& data)
{
}


int main() {
    int ea = 22;
    fun<>(ea); // 1) Why no matching call? Why isn't this a l-value reference?
    fun2<>(0); // 3) Why does this work? 0 can't bind to a reference

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers.

Comment: It would be nice if you asked one question per question.

Comment: Your whole thing boils down to "is `const T&&` a universal reference?" which is trivially Googleable.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit not point 3

Comment: For that one refer to my first comment. This is a Q&A not a Qs&A!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer for each question:

1) It's l-value reference, but `fun` needs r-value reference, so `fun2<>(ea)` is ok

2) From Scott Mayers answer:

https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

> Universal references can only occur in the form “T&&”!  Even the
>   simple addition of a const qualifier is enough to disable the
>   interpretation of “&&” as a universal reference

3) But in `fun2` the parameter is **const** T& data and therefore it works.

One more good video about references: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11

Answer (score 3):

1. No, `const T&& data` means rvalue reference to `const T`.
2. It's not a forwarding reference. Only the form `T&&` is. The rule is given in the standard at [temp.deduct.call]/3; emphasis mine.

> ... If `P` is an rvalue reference to a **cv-unqualified template parameter** and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in
>   place of `A` for type deduction.
>
> A const lvalue reference can bind to an rvalue, even a literal such as `0`.